# Docker react frontend in ubuntu 20.04 not reloading

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

I setted up docker in ubuntu 20.04, everything works properly except the frontend is not reloading everytime I changed my frontend code.
This is my docker-compos.yml file

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  mysql-container:
    ...
  backend:
    ...
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    cache_from:
     - pals-crm-2_frontend_1:latest
    environment:
      REACT_APP_API_URL: "${REACT_APP_API_URL}"
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      # One-way volume to use node_modules from inside image
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    command: npm start
    #command: nodemon --exec npm start
volumes:
  mysql-storage:
```

and the following is my frontend(react) Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest
# RUN apk update && apk add python make g++
WORKDIR /home/jay/sprint3/pals-crm-2/frontend

#RUN yarn global add nodemon

# Install dependencies
COPY package.json ./

COPY . ./

ENV API_URL $API_URL

ENV REACT_APP_API_URL $REACT_APP_API_URL

RUN yarn install --network-timeout 500000
```

I know there should some error in my working directory of these files (they should be in the same file), but no matter which directory I tried to put them together, when I run `docker-compose up --build` , I got this error

```
EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/node_modules/.cache'
```

My initial working directory for those docker file is just /app/ , and my friend who is using mac can run this without any error, but I cannot make it work in ubuntu. So I have to put the volume and work dir in different file and my code is not refreshing everytime I change my code, and I have to rebuild the containers everytime even I changed one line of code. Thank in advance if anyone can help me solve this.

Comment: Can you use a host Node environment for day-to-day development (and delete the `volumes:` block from the Compose setup)?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm using host Node env, but after I delete the volumes block the I can still build the containers. However, the page is still not refreshing after I changed the code, and I still need to rebuild to see the changes.